# How to add "Arabian" or "Microtone" or "Quarter-tone" support to jMusic?

Tags: java, jar, midi, notation

I have been working lately on a program that transcribes WAV files having a single and monophonic instrument, more likely this instrument is Vocal.

This program converts the given WAV file into Sheet Music or "SCORE".

The thing is:

- I want to draw sheet music of every note in the WAV file, for example:

  - the WAV file contains the following notes:

    - C     D     ***E***     F     G#     Bb
  - ***E*** is neither natural nor sharp nor flat, it is Half-Flat.

Such note can be represented in MIDI using the ***PITCH BEND*** as follows:

---

**MIDI REPRESENTATION**

NOTE_ON   60   PITCHBEND  25

This means that note number 60 which is effectively "C4" is pressed with pitch bend value of 25 making it C Half-Sharp or C Half-Flat.

---

Using jMusic, I was able to draw the sheet music of everything except Half-Flat and Half-Sharp notes.

I used jMusic to get the sheet music in the following pattern :

> **FIRST STAGE:**
>
> RECORD >> SAMPLE >> SEGMENTATION >> FFT >> MIDI
>
> **SECOND STAGE (USING JMUSIC):**
>
> MIDI-TO-SMF >> SMF-TO-SCORE >> NOTATE(SCORE)

I figured out how does jMusic really work, and I figured out that it uses images saved in "GIF format" having size of "18 x 56" in the following directory: *" jm.gui.cpn.graphics "*

My Question:**How can I make jMusic detect "pitch-bend value" and draw the corresponding Half-Flat or Half-Sharp accidentals?**

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how popular jMusic is but in case you can't find anyone who knows about it have you tried searching the docs for 'Accidentals' or similar?  E.g. try:

http://www.google.com/search?q=accidentals+site:http%3A%2F%2Fjmusic.ci.qut.edu.au

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to 'notate' arabic/microtonal music automatically: good luck

If you are having problems with 'just-off' intonation in the input, I suggest a pitch shift filter to globally center the intonation to your tuning (e.g. using Ardour, LADSPA filters, sox (commandline) or many others)

Otherwise you could look into a kind of rounding algorithm. Also look at the documentation using the search keyword 'cents' since that should lead you to info pertaining to nonstandard tunings.